# Gradle line ending char for sourceSets

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, newline, lf

My **build.gradle** file contains the following:

```
sourceSets {
   main { output.resourcesDir = "build/app" }
}
```

This is working well, content of `src/main/resources` is correctly copied into build/app folder.

However, I have some resources (scripts) for which I need to force the line ending character. I need to always force an `LF`. In order word, need to be sure that we never have any `CRLF`.

> Question: is it possible to filter resources included via a
>   sourceSets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works well:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.FixCrLfFilter

processResources {
    filesMatching('**/*.sh') {
        filter(FixCrLfFilter.class,
        eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("lf"))
    }
    filesMatching('**/*.properties') {
        filter(FixCrLfFilter.class,
        eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("lf"))
    }
    filesMatching('**/*.xml') {
        filter(FixCrLfFilter.class,
        eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("lf"))
    }
}
```